# Windows 7 / Internet Explorer 8

Tags: windows-7, internet, windows-explorer

I am a shop owner at zazzle.com.  About six weeks ago, when my computer was running on Windows XP/IE7, my sites, as well as zazzle's homepages went out on me.  I can only see part of each page.  Since that time, I have a new computer running Windows 7/IE8, thinking that would solve the issue.  It did not.

Zazzle's emails told me to download Firefox and/or download Internet Explorer 7.  I tried Firefox and was getting a different problem at the zazzle site.  Now I was getting only the 'view source' pages on zazzle's homepages and my own shop sites as well.

Question: Can I download IE 7 onto my IE 8 computer?  Can this be done without loading that compilation of internet explorer 1 through 8?  What do you think is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Some ISPs cache content, it could be a problem with your ISP not you.

Comment: If true, @Moab, then the Zazzle website would be using incorrect cache headers, and then those very same headers would be used by the browser too?

Comment: Maybe the ISP cache servers are acting up, just possibility. Its a miracle the internet even works, it amazes me every day I use it.

Comment: Maybe a failing router, anything is possible at this point.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should give it a try to the internet explorer collection, or try other browsers, as a matter of fact this seems as a problem with zazzle's coding, but you can't fix that so, have you tried compatibility mode in IE8? is the little broken sheet next to the address bar.

Comment: OR: Go to Tools->Compatibility View Settings, and add zazzle.com

Answer (score 1):

I just checked zazzle, including at least starting the sign-in process as a store owner (I don't have a store to actually finish), from IE 7 and 8 on XP and IE 8 on 7.  No problems here.  To me, that means look at your connection to the store - is it clean all the way through?  Do you maybe have a proxy server or content filter that might be interferring with something like a javascript resource?  I'd ask about a cached script or css file, but you've completely switched computers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like content filtering to me, not a browser issue. Zazzle works fine with both IE7 and IE8, so that isn't the issue, I would have suspected something wrong in your local cache, but that seems to be not the case, not least since you changed operating system.

Are you running any local content filtering (parental controls, web filtering etc.)? Are you using a proxy server or tunnelling through anything other than your what your ISP provides?